# How to block external connections for an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, connections

I have an oracle database (11g-r2) on my (windows) computer for development, and I am trying to forbid any outside connections. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: firewall? stop the listener?

Comment: bind listener to localhost(127.0.0.1) only

Comment: Thanks. And how I do it please. I forgot to say that I am working on a windows installation. Editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is really dependant on your environment.  There are numerous options, from hardware firewalls, to software firewalls, to sqlnet.ora parameters.  The first two are beyond the scope of this site.

The quickest, probably, is sqlnet.ora.

Have a look at the tcp.invited_nodes parameter:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF237

This goes hand in hand with the tcp.validnode_checking parameter:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF238

Answer (score 1):

Bind the listener to localhost only:

```
LISTENER=
(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS_LIST=
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc))))
```